# Visual Studio code just had a major meltdown (exlamationpoint)

Tags: node.js, typescript, module

```
Version: 1.77.3 (user setup)
Commit: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
Date: 2023-04-12T09:16:02.548Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Sandboxed: Yes
```

[image]

```
{
  "name": "sqlgen",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@bobfrankston/hlib": "^1.0.43",
    "@types/msnodesql": "^0.2.30",
    "@types/mssql": "^6.0.7",
    "@types/sqlite3": "^3.1.8",
    "@types/tedious": "^4.0.3",
    "dbdefs": "file:../../../../homecontrol/utils/dbdefs",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.6",
    "sqllib": "file:../sqllib"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0"
  }
}
```

I've been doing fine by making sure I have all packages marked as modules and targeting esnext. This is a NodeJS app. Suddenly it's spouting spurious complaints. I'm going to try to figure this out, but I'm getting increasingly afraid of VSC as it seems to have an attitude.

All the included modules seem to work just fine  To add to this, the error claims that the problem is that I have a module and am trying to load commonjs but than
[image]

it is telling me that I"m not in a module